# AliasQuery is deprecated in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1

Tags: spring, spring-data, deprecated, spring-data-elasticsearch

How do I migrate from Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 [IndexOperations.addAlias](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/IndexOperations.html#addAlias-org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.AliasQuery-) to Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1 [IndexOperations.alias](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/IndexOperations.html#alias-org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.index.AliasActions-)?

I have the following method:

```
@Autowired ElasticsearchOperations operations;

public boolean addAlias(String indexName, String aliasName) {
    IndexCoordinates index = IndexCoordinates.of(indexName);
    IndexOperations indexOperations = operations.indexOps(index);
    // Create an alias
    return indexOperations.addAlias(new AliasQuery(aliasName));
}
```

How do I migrate it to the new [AliasActions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/index/AliasActions.html) API?

The [official migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.0-4.1.deprecations) was not helpful.

Comment: See https://www.sothawo.com/2020/11/implement-a-rolling-index-strategy-with-spring-data-elasticsearch-4-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the tests, for example at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplateTests.java#L2784-L2830

```
    AliasActions aliasActions = new AliasActions();
    aliasActions.add(new AliasAction.Add(AliasActionParameters.builder()
            .withIndices(indexOperations.getIndexCoordinates().getIndexNames()).withAliases("aliasA", "aliasB").build()));

    indexOperations.alias(aliasActions);
```